# Porting application Domino 9.0.1 Xpages to Domino 10 with new approach

Tags: url-rewriting, xpages, lotus-domino, ssjs, domino-appdev-pack

I have dozens of applications written in XPAGES (Domino 9.0.1). From the Webinar on Domino V10 seen a few weeks ago there has been a lot of talk about the new approach to development. The new approach is very similar to the MEAN development stack. For those like me who wrote dozens of applications using XPAGES with SSJS and Java and want to start writing new applications (also giving a look at the architecture to micro service) must rewrite all over again. I imagine that all the SSJS code is lost and this is certain and I believe partly the Java code. What do you think is the best approach to migrate applications to the new way to develop..I've been forced to recode the code in node.js. For you the development mode with the Xpages will be permanently abandoned in favor of the new approach.

Thank you

Comment: So: Whats your question? Is there any?

Comment: Re: "I've been forced to recode the code in node.js."  That's not the intent.  Your XPages applications will continue to work in V10 and beyond.  The Node.js option is meant to be complimentary.  If you want to get started with Node.js, Express, React and Domino (NERD), I would start with the first three characters of the acronym.  There are plenty of useful tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not both?

Keep the applications that are working for you, and consider coding new types of applications using N.E.R.D.

Comment: Can I run the React interface outside the Domino database? If I put the React code inside the Domino database it would always be a monolithic approach at the end.
If I wanted to put the React code out of the Domino database what kind of authentication should I have?How do I propagate credentials to services?

Comment: Sure.  You could ship the React code in a webpacked bundle off of the node server that houses the static web code and the data APIs for your application.  The APIs can be REST, or GraphQL, or whatever.  Don't forget... never webpack domino-db into your web code, the credentials would be exposed for everyone to see.

Comment: Credentials and authentication are going to be handled by OAuth.  The second release (soon) of the appdev pack will have the preview of the IAM server that implements the OAuth stuff.  It won't yet be ready for you to use with the node module... but it will integrate with existing calendar and busytime apis.  Next release after that should see full OAuth support for node apps as well.